# What's the best practice to create a modern form, accessible etc? Especially, label vs placeholder fight

Tags: html, forms, label, accessibility, placeholder

I'm looking for advices and feedback, as I can't decide what's the way to go.

I'm building HTML5 form and I want them to be as easy as possible to use.
That's why, I always used label to explain what to enter in a field, and placeholder as an example of a value with a good format.

So, my code always looks like:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <label for="origin-field">Please enter your origin address</label>
            <input type="text" name="origin" id="origin-field" placeholder="23th Street, New York City" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="destination-field">Please enter you destination address</label>
            <input type="text" name="destination" id="destination-field" placeholder="Ashbury Street, San Francisco" required />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

This code is accessible, labels are linked to inputs using the for attribute, in short, it respects the best practices. It has other UX advantages: if the user clicks in the input and then is distracted, the label is always displayed next to it and can easily remind them what information the input is waiting.

However, my product owner and my designer deeply want me to remove the label and use the placeholder instead, so the code would be

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="origin" id="origin-field" placeholder="Origin address" required />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="text" name="destination" id="destination-field" placeholder="Destination address" required />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

The two arguments are, it uses less space on screen / is more beautiful and also, users mistake the example value as something they could have entered and don't get why the field isn't empty (this is of course a contrast problem, the placeholder is light grey and should not be mistaken with a really value, in deep black, but eh, according to the PO, they do).

What should I do? Should I fight to try to keep the label in the design? If I put a `display: none` on the label, will it be still read by screen-readers? Should I put a `position: absolute; left: -9999px; top: -9999px;` instead?

What's the current best practice?

Comment: https://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/

Comment: https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2011/02/html5-accessibility-chops-the-placeholder-attribute/

Answer (score 5):

The [official spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) for the `placeholder` attribute specifically says to **not** use the placeholder as a label.

> **Warning!** Use of the placeholder attribute as a replacement for a label can reduce the accessibility and usability of the control

There are lots of issues with placeholder text:

- the text can be mistaken for content that's already entered
- the text has insufficient [color contrast](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html)
- the text disappears when the input field receives focus

Many of these are cognitive issues, which is a [huge area](https://www.w3.org/TR/coga-user-research/) in accessibility.
Even if all of these reasons seem "silly" because *you* would never have any of these problems, *you* are not a representative sample of everyone.

Some alternatives are to have a "floating" label that appears "inside" the input field but when the field receives focus, the label floats outside the field.  [Brad Frost](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/float-label-pattern/) has a really nice example.  [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/) has one but I don't like the aesthetics (but you could certainly tweak that).  To see a live example, [Discover Card](https://www.discover.com/) uses them in their login area.

If you want instructional text to be associated with the input field, for example to show a date format (mm/dd/yy vs ddmmmyy vs whatever) or email format or phone number format, etc, the text should be visible on the screen and separate from the field but associated with the field via the `aria-describedby` attribute.  For example:

```
<label for="phone">Phone number</label>
<input id="phone" aria-describedby="info">
<span id="info">(xxx)-xxx-xxxx</span>
```

Of course, from a general UX perspective, you shouldn't have input fields that the user can type invalid text.  You should try to figure out what they typed and format it for them.  There are lots of phone number algorithms for letting the user type whatever format they want, or letting them type a date in any format (although something like 1/2/18 can be hard to decide whether it's Jan 2 or Feb 1, but using locality can help), or using a "selector" widget to choose a date or a country or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

Having just placeholder text instead of labels have some problems.

1. Placeholder text disappears when user starts typing in the input field. Then it violates SC 3.2.2 as there's no visible label or instructions.
2. When text is entered over top of the placeholder text, some Screen reader and browser combinations will populate the placeholder value as an accessible name in the Accessibility API when there is no other label in the code and some Screen readers don't. So they are not evenly supported yet.
3. Even if labels are provided as Screen reader only or Offscreen text, it benefits SR users, but having no visual label is a problem for users with Cognitive disabilities, low attention deficit etc.

One solution would be to use Floating labels. These are place holder text that moves out of the input field to become a label when user starts typing.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I know about floating labels, I saw some material design framework like [materializecss](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) doing that (see on this page, when clicking on the example autocomplete field). I should have mentionned that in my question. Is this the best practice we can have at the moment?

Comment: Screen readers have been identifying floating labels that are implemented correctly as Labels. So I think that's the reliable solution I am aware of at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Answering your questions:

> What's the best practice to create a modern form, accessible etc?
>   Especially, label vs placeholder fight

Use bootstrap and font awesome, if you combined them, you will get an awesome bootstraped form :) use form-group

> What should I do? Should I fight to try to keep the label in the
>   design? If I put a display: none on the label, will it be still read
>   by screen-readers? Should I put a position: absolute; left: -9999px;
>   top: -9999px; instead?
>
> What's the current best practice?

Same as before, use bootstrap an get the things done with less effort. Please forget that kind of things like hidding stuff on the DOM because that is not SEO friendly :(

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

[Fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css)

Comment: Anyway if you want some help put your css and maybe could do something :)

Comment: Hm, at least tell me how these libraries solve the problem. "Use fontawesome" means "use icons". Then how? Why? Those are the questions. I'm not asking the way to do it, I'm asking what to do.